# Why is my xml the same after changing the content?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I store objects in my xml file. After editing the object and serializing, the content in the xml file stays the same as before. However, when I read the file in VS again (StreamReader), I get the edited file data.

What is wrong? How can the data be saved and not saved at the same time? And what can I do to get an refreshed xml file after editing?

Here is my C#:

```
List<User> data = GetFileData();
User testUser = data.Single(x => x.Id == this.ID);

testUser.Name = "Alex";

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<User>));
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"res\users.xml"))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, data);
}
```

Xml before and after processing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ArrayOfUser>
  <User>
    <Name>Carl</Name>
    <Age>54</Age>
    <Id>3549</Id>
    ...
  </User>
  ...
</ArrayOfUser>
```

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say probably you're looking at the wrong copy of the file. Don't forget when you run the code in VS it makes a separate folder for the built code, different than where the source code is. Since you're specifying a relative path for the XML file, the copy being modified should be relative to that executable folder, not your source folder

Comment: You are right. It works using the full path.

Comment: The relative path leads to \bin\Debug\...\res\users.xml. When using the full path you see the changed data immediately. But using the relative path file there arent any changes. How is that? It should have the changed data till the next debug process (when it gets refreshed by the source file) am I right?